# What is this nut, and can I remove it and put it back without damaging it?

Tags: maintenance

I am working on my bike and starting with derusting. The nut in the picture below has got some rust on it and since I am going for a proper looking-after I want to make sure everything is taken care of.

My question is, what is the purpose of this nut?  How can I get it out to derust it; will I damage it by removing it and how would I put it back on?

The photo below is a picture of the front wheel hub with its quick axle and front brake disc removed.

[image: close-up view of the side of a front disc brake hub mounting, focused on a hexagonal nut threaded on the axle]

Comment: I can't see any rust.  If your wheel turns freely and smoothly in the bike, perhaps leave it for now and work on something else.

Comment: Even if there were a bit of surface rust on the outside: The important thing is grease inside the bearing and the correct bearing preload.

Comment: "The nut in the picture below has got some rust on it" hu?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is a Locknut, and it will be firmly cinched against the backside of a Cone nut, which is part of the bearings.

In your case there is a rubber bushing on the outside, which is likely stretched around a lip of some sort.  Peel that off carefully and you'll see an axle like this:

[image: ""]
 Look at Bearing Cone and Locknut on the right side.

[image: ""]
 your rubber bushing is probably clipped over the spacer.

Absolutely you can undo it, but you'll need a suitable spanner on the other side, and to reset the bearing preload you will need the correct size of Cone spanner, which could be anything from 12mm to 18mm.  A cone spanner is a very thin metal tool, and a regular spanner will not fit.

You can totally do this, but its hard to describe in words.  If you can have the bike out of service for a while, give it a go.  If you need it working by the next morning, perhaps time the repair for your weekend.